# What are restas render-objects?

Tags: web, lisp, hunchentoot

When i try to compile the render-object method shown here in the documentation http://restas.lisper.ru/en/manual/special-pages.html,

```
(defmethod restas:render-object ((designer mydrawer)
                                 (code (eql hunchentoot:+http-internal-server-error+)))
  (setf (hunchentoot:content-type*) "text/plain")
  "Oh, all very bad")
```

it gives

```
There is no class named RESTAURANT::MYDRAWER SIMPLE-ERROR
```

How do these render-object thingies work ?

Comment: To better understand it, you should read about generic functions: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-generic-functions.html
In your case, you don't have a class `mydrawer` defined in your current package

Answer (score 0):

render-object is a generic function that takes a rendering object, which is either the object passed to `:render-method` for `define-route` or the value of `*default-render-method*`, and the object to render. It then renders that object (usually as text, although you could probably render it to an octet array as well).

The example assumes that you have a class called mydrawer. To get this working you would need to do something like the following:

```
(defclass mydrawer () ())
(defmethod restas:render-object ((designer mydrawer)
                                 (code (eql hunchentoot:+http-internal-server-error+)))
  (setf (hunchentoot:content-type*) "text/plain")
        "Oh, all very bad")
(defmethod restas:render-object ((designer mydrawer) obj)
    ;; Default rendering of objects goes here,
    ;; this will just call the default render method
    (restas:render-object nil obj))
```

And then use an instance of `mydrawer` as the render method either for individual routes, or for a restas module.